# Detect if something is a length?

Tags: expl3, programming, lengths

Is there a way in LaTeX to detect if something is a length with a function of the form:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\iflength{m m m}{%CODE HERE%}
```

where:

- the first parameter is the thing to be tested
- the second is the true branch
- the third is the false branch

---

**Test code**

```
\documentclass[preview = true, varwidth = true]{standalone}

\NewDocumentCommand\iflength{m m m}{
    %CODE HERE
}

\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
\newcommand{\commandlength}{10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
\newcommand{\commandstring}{xxx}

\begin{document}
\iflength{\mylength}{true}{false}        % should be true
\iflength{\commandlength}{true}{false}   % should be false (ideally, but ok if true)
\iflength{\commandstring}{true}{false}   % should be false
\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean testing if it's a `skip` register I presume? I wonder what all of these rather odd questions are about, fundamentally: it feels 'X-Y' to me (i.e. you are asking various things that you think help with some other task, but we need to know the real issue to help).

Comment: you want a skip register to be true, what about a dimen register? what about a primitive dimen such as \hsize or a primitive skip such as `\baselineskip`  the question is massively under specified and why would you ever need this test?

Comment: you have tagged this exp3 and in expl3 the question doesn't arise as the variable would not be called `\mylength` it would be called `\my_foo_skip`  and you would know it was a skip without testing. That is why L3 has the naming convention it has.